# Java- %.2f format specifier throwing MissingFormatArgumentException

Tags: java, format-specifiers

I'm trying to use format specifiers in a Java program to show only the first 2 decimal places of a `double` variable I'm printing.

Right now, my statement to print the `double` is `System.out.format("Total = $%.2f" + value);` (value is the double in question).

When I run my program, it prints the "Total = $" without any issues, then immediately gives a `MissingFormatArgumentException`.

full error log in console:

```
Total = $Exception in thread "main" java.util.MissingFormatArgumentException: Format specifier '%.3f'
    at java.util.Formatter.format(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.PrintStream.format(Unknown Source)
    at Account.getBalance(Account.java:21)
    at testAccount.main(testAccount.java:4)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you provide your code?

Comment: @Filburt: I rolled back your edit, because there was no improvement at all ... it just made it worse.

Comment: @Tom Andy pray in what way did formatting the error message as a blockquote instead of code formatting make it worse?

Comment: @Filburt In my opinion a block quote should only be used for quoting text, not source code. The problem is, that there is no formatting and no indentation. In this case ( [your edit](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/29736175/2) ) the stack trace was "harder" to read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parameters of the `System.out.print` are not `("...%.2f" + x)`, it's `("...%.2f", x)`.

Try this instead:

`System.out.format("Total = $%.2f", value)`;